# Make font of \subsubsection bold in amsart

Tags: fonts, amsart

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mainsectionstyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{2}%
    \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
    {\normalfont\bfseries}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \mainsectionstyle
    \section{klasdjklasd}
    \subsection{daksdjasdj}
    \subsubsection{adjklsjkasdjklas}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

How do I change the italic font to bold font in the subsubsection? (Maybe also the font in the subsection, because it is by default bold)

Comment: `\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{section}{3}....` most likely

Comment: `\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}...` indeed works. Did something wrong the first time I tried.

Comment: You may have to adjust some of the fontsize etc. and indentation parameters as well, but the main error is the wrong number after : `3` means subsection, `1` is section, `2` is subsection etc. And I meant `\@startsection{subsubsection}` actually -- sorry, I was too fast

Comment: Oh this is interesting. Did not know what the numbers mean. Thanks.

Comment: On the off chance that one of you is still checking this website-  I couldn't make this example work. Do you have the exact command you ended up using? @user31729

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easy to change the fonts for the sectioning commands; they're all independently
defined.

from `amsart.cls':

```
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
```

for `\subsubsection`, change `\itshape` to `\bfseries`.

you say "maybe also the font in the subsection, because if is by default bold",
but you don't say what you want to change it to.  in any event, it should be fairly obvious what to do -- replace `\bfseries` by whatever you want.

this change (and all similar definitions) should go in the preamble.
they also need to be wrapped in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` since they
contain commands with `@` as part of the name.

Comment: I do not want to change the bold font of subsection, but I wanted to know how I could, since it works the same way as subsubsection and section. Thanks. Everything clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The command that work, summarized from the comments, is:

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}%
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
  
  \makeatother
```